# How to transpile styled components into an NPM package?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, styled-components

I have a styled component that I want to build into an NPM package and be able to import into other projects.

My styled component is something like this:

```
// src/StyledDiv.styles.js
import styled from "styled-components"

const StyledDiv = styled("div")`
  border: solid red 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 15px;
`

export default StyledDiv
```

I then have a build script that should transpile my code into a dist folder:

`"build": "babel src -d dist --copy-files --ignore './src/**/*.test.js'",`

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

I then run `npm link` in my styled component project and then `npm link <styled component>` in my other project in order to try import it but seem to get the error:

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Which I believe arrives from babel not transpiling my styled component correctly so when I import the built files in dist, the app crashes.

My full package.json is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "my-styled-component",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest ./src/**/*.test.js --notify --detectOpenHandles",
    "test:watch": "jest ./src/**/*.test.js --notify --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "build": "babel src -d dist --copy-files --ignore './src/**/*.test.js'",
    "lint:css": "stylelint './src/**/*.styles.js'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-styled-components": "^6.3.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "^10.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^2.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.6.0",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0",
    "styled-tools": "^1.7.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like the desired component is not exported successfully as expected. Please go and check the /dist/index.js and verify if there is actually a component that was exported.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to import react in the component file.

```
import React from 'react';
```

Comment: I added the import but it didn't seem to make any difference. I don't see why I would need to import it since I am not actually using React in my styled component. The file that imports my styled component package would definitely need to import React but I wouldn't have thought my styled component would...

Answer (score 0):

You need use this in `.babelrc`:

```
    presets: [
      '@babel/env',
      '@babel/react',
    ],
```

Comment: I changed my `.babelrc` to `.babelrc.js` and added your suggestion as ```module.exports = {
  presets: [
    require('@babel/preset-env'),
    require('@babel/react')
  ]
}``` as the format you posted didn't seem to work. Unfortunatly I am still getting the origin error

Comment: If this does not help, perhaps it makes sense not to assemble the component at all but to publish it in its original form by entrusting build to the user of your component?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but am I not already doing that? I am essentially trying to bundle my `.style` files, the required node_modules and ignore any tests. The use of the component still has to worry about the rest.

Comment: I thought you were trying to build your component through Babel before publishing. If this is not the case, then simply add  ```"main": "PATH/NAME-YOUR-COMPONENT"``` instead of ```"main": "dist/index.js"``` in your ```package.json```.

Comment: If your repository and module are not private give links to github and npm.

Comment: Sorry if this is confusing but yes I am trying to build before publishing. As I mentioned, I don't want to bundle test files, devDependencies etc. I want to provide the user with usable styled components. Here is the repo if you'd like to have a look: https://gitlab.com/Stretch0/lattice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193043/discussion-between-stretch0-and-timofey-goncharov).